# Overdamped bead on a rotating hoop

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics

[image]

My doubt is related to the centrifugal force added here.
M$\rho \omega^2$ is the centrifugal force experienced by the bead relative to the vertical axis where it is rotating in a circular motion with radius $\rho$.
My doubt was that besides this motion, the bead is also moving in a circular motion with radius $r$ in the vertical plane. Why dont we add the centrifugal force from that motion which should be normal to the bead?

Comment: $~b\,\dot\phi~$ is a torque not force ? and the centrifugal force  is $~-m\,\omega^2\,r\,\hat r~$ thus if r is a constant it doesn't affect  the EOM

Comment: of course $~+m\,\omega^2\,r\hat r~$